# End of the border style in css

Tags: html, css

I have two containers, with zero distance between them, each has its own border. At the exact point two borders touch (see image below) the upper border is truncated in the form of a triangle, which irritates me a lot. I've done my research, but found no way to fix that, except adding outer container with overlaying border.

[image]

Is there any better way to make that triangle disappear?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you put your css?

Comment: If possible can you please share your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from having borders defined but the color is actually set to the background, if you add border-top: none; and border-bottom:none; to your css on the the tables the issue will be resolved. The triangle you speak of is the border transitioning from the left border to the bottom or top border.

Comment: While this is a _possible_ cause of the problem, in general it's better to ask the OP for clarification (in the form of runnable code that demonstrates the issue) so they won't leave us guessing.

Comment: I agree, but I also don't want people to be afraid to answer or ask. I had some extra time to answer and maybe he was in a pinch and didn't know what to ask. I'm sure if I had offered a poor solution I would have been down voted to oblivion. :)

Answer (score -1):

May be this is because you are having `border-radius` so only you getting rounded corner at bottom. Please remove `radius` and try .